# Why meta name="viewport" tag is not used by big brands like Amazon, Zomato, Swiggy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive

I went to websites like Amazon, Zomato, and Swiggy when I opened the developer tool I realized they are not using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">`.

If I load their website in desktop mode and then I decrease the screen width using the dev tool, the layout does not change (as the viewport tag is not added). I found that their layout type is based on the initial loading width of the screen.

How they are achieving this? Suggest any correct method (industry standard) to do this in React and what is the benefit of this?

Thanks in advance.

Tried to find it by myself but there is not a single article present about this.

Answer (score 0):

Google also does this as well in google.com.
They use the User Agent String of the device and serve a different website
depending on its value.

You can test that yourself using the browser devtools.

First open devtools with `Ctrl + Shift + I` or `F12`,
then click the 3 dots -> More tools -> Network conditions.

Now you will see the tab `Network conditions`.

[image]

You can now use your custom User Agent String or select one of the provided there.

[image]

If you select a mobile User Agent and then reload,
the website will change to the mobile version.

Comment: Hey Xion, Thank you for your answer. Can you please suggest the correct method (industry standard) to do this in React and what is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: @SandipDas, you usually just go with responsive design instead of doing this kind of thing which I guess it needs extra work to get it done. I don't really know how you would actually accomplish something like that if you really wanted, but obviously this is related to backend when generating the response to the user request.

Answer (score 0):

I check it and I find out something. the meta tag appears if it's on a phone or the size of the screen is like a phone. so do this resize the page size then refresh the page then check the meta element.
[image]

Comment: Hey Milad, Thank you for your answer. Can you please suggest the correct method (industry standard) to do this in React and what is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: Hi @SandipDas, I think maybe to optimize the layout for different device sizes. I recommend that use the viewport meta tag in HTML. but if you want to do this you can change the header with the Helmet package in a useEffect. for the first time that the website load, it just checks the viewport and if you need to add a meta tag in there. or you can use js to append the tag in the head tag. I'll put another answer and in there explain more.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why some websites do not use the meta name="viewport" tag, such as:

- The website may have been designed specifically for desktop users and may not be optimised for mobile devices.
- The website may have been developed before the widespread adoption of mobile devices and responsive web design.
- The website may use a different approach to handle the display of web pages on mobile devices, such as adaptive design or separate mobile sites.

However, the fact that some big brands like Amazon, Zomato, and Swiggy do not use it in their websites **does not necessarily mean that it is not important or that it should not be used.**

It is worth noting that the absence of the meta name="viewport" tag **may lead to issues** with the display of web pages on mobile devices, such as content not fitting on the screen, text being too small or too large, and the need for users to zoom in or out to read the content. (*as you have already witnessed)*

Comment: In what way does this general stuff answer the question? And where does the OP talk about zooming?

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag adds to the `head` whenever we need it.
To do it in React project, you can use useEffect in the App file because we need that useEffect to run every time someone opens the website.

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
    meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    document.head.appendChild(meta);
  }, []);
```

or you can use the `Helmet` package.

```
<Helmet>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</Helmet>
```

you can check if the viewport is smaller than something like 765px then the device is a Phone.

```
if(window.innerWidth < 765){...}
```